# Appropriate use of keyword "new" in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Please consider the following code :

```
string[] words =
{ "Too", "much", "of", "anything", "is" ,"good","for","nothing"};

var groups =from word in words
            orderby word ascending
            group word by word.Length into lengthGroups
            orderby lengthGroups.Key descending
           select new {Length=lengthGroups.Key, Words=lengthGroups};

   foreach (var group in groups)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Words of length " + group.Length);
     foreach (string word in group.Words)
     Console.WriteLine(" " + word);
   }
```

Why do we need the keyword "new" here?.can you give some other simple example to understand it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new` keyword is used to create an instance of a class.

In this case it's an anonymous class. You can use the same syntax to create an anonmyous object outside the scope of a LINQ query:

```
object o = new { Name = "Göran" };
```

Comment: Side note: `new` also initializes structs

Comment: Thanks Guffa for your explanation.It helped me a lot. :) Have a nice day?

Answer (score 10):

The `new { A = "foo", B = "bar }` syntax defines an anonymous type with properties `A` and `B`, with values "foo" and "bar" respectively. You are doing this to return multiple values per row.

Without *some* kind of new object, you could only return (for example) the `Key`. To return multiple properties, a values is required. In this case, an anonymous type is fine since this data is only used local to this query.

You could also define your own `class`, and use `new` with that instead:

```
new MyType("abc", "def") // via the constructor
```

or

```
new MyType { A = "abc", B = "def" } // via object initializer
```

Byt that is overkill unless `MyType` has some useful meaning outside of this context.

Comment: Even if you did only want one of the properties (say Key), you might still want to use an anonymous type so that you could give the property a more meaningful name.  This aspect is probably best seen when selecting out a subset of properties out of an existing object in a LINQ enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is creating an instance of an anonymous type with properties `Length` and `Words` for each item in the `lengthGroups` enumeration.

Are you asking (a) why the syntax reads as is does, or (b) why the code is creating an anonymous type?

Answer (score 0):

The new keyword is creating an anonymous type in your query.  Anonymous types in Linq allow you to shape your query results.

Comment: Simplifies rather than allows... You can do the same with a named class.